# How should I test a lamdba function with a DynamoDbClient?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, testing, aws-lambda

I'm developing a java lamdba function in plain java. I want to unit test my code but my class contains a DynamoDbClient as private field. What is the recommended way to test this? Can I mock it somehow? Should I put the client in a different class?

```
private DynamoDbClient amazonDynamoDB;

public String handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context) {

    this.initDynamoDbClient();
    // logic
}

private void initDynamoDbClient() {
    this.amazonDynamoDB = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(Region.region)
            .build();
}
```

so far my class looks like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to inject the client in the constructor, and do the initialization at the handler level, so you can easily mock any class using the db injection.

Comment: Would you recommend having 2 constructors? Creating one constructor with a single param (DynamoDbClient) and another without parameters but with DynamoDbClient initialization?

Comment: Yes. I would do two constructors

Answer (score 2):

You can use singleton pattern and get the unique DynamoDbClient's instantiated client every time you need it

```
private static DynamoDbClient instance;

public static DynamoDbClient getInstance(){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(Region.region)
            .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a new class contain these static fields and then mock it in a unit test. Am I understanding correctly? Because if this is the case it's a little tricky to mock the static method. Please feel free to correct me.